# IOS Dictonary to get the Defination of particular Word

Tags: ios

I am looking to access iOS dictionary in my application. Is there any in build library of iOS , that provide the definition of a particular word.

I found many third Party API's to do that work but they are paid.

Looking for the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
  if UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: "word") {
            let libraryVC = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "word")
            self.present(libraryVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

The Code itself is pretty clear, it doesn't need explanation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, may be you give try to [UIReferenceLibraryViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller):

Beside definition it includes checking for whether a given word is defined or not. you can use it as follows:

**Objective-C:**

```
if ([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:@"definition"]) {
    UIReferenceLibraryViewController* ref = 
        [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:@"definition"];
    [currentViewController presentViewController:ref animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
if UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: "definition") {
      let libraryVC = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "definition")
      self.present(libraryVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```